# How to Store birt report in pdf/.xls format in application folder

Tags: weblogic, birt, eclipse-kepler

In birt report i can able to show the report on screen as well as an attachment in .pdf anf .xls format.
For this i have used one method runReportAsAttachment() and passing the parameters and *.rptdesign file location path to BirtServletEngine.In Service method i got the report in byte format and to save this byte in pdf format, i have wriiten below code,

```
try{
            File saveFile = new File("/report/SaveAsFile.pdf");
            if(!saveFile.exists()) {
                saveFile.createNewFile();
            } 
            FileOutputStream fileToDownload = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);

            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
//response got from birtservlet engine 
            ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
            //
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[10000];
            bos.write(bytes);
            bos.writeTo(output);
            pdfBytes = bos.toByteArray();       
            //
            fileToDownload.write(pdfBytes);
            fileToDownload.flush();
            fileToDownload.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
```

Empty Pdf is generated under /report folder. Please let me know how to store birt report in folder?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EngineConfig engineConfig = new EngineConfig();

```
    engineConfig.setBIRTHome("D:/Reporting/Birt/Birt Softwares/birt-runtime-4_3_2/ReportEngine");
    engineConfig.setLogConfig("C:/temp", Level.FINE);
    Platform.startup(engineConfig);

    IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform.createFactoryObject(IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);

    IReportEngine engine = factory.createReportEngine(engineConfig);

    IReportRunnable openReportDesign = engine.openReportDesign("D:/Birt/Reprt Work/.metadata/br/RemoteSystemsTempFiles/test_report.rptdesign");

    IRunAndRenderTask createRunAndRenderTask = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(openReportDesign);

    PDFRenderOption taskOption = new PDFRenderOption();
    String outPutFile = "D:/out.pdf";
    taskOption.setOutputFormat("pdf");
    taskOption.setOutputFileName(outPutFile);
    createRunAndRenderTask.setRenderOption(taskOption);
    createRunAndRenderTask.run();
    createRunAndRenderTask.close();
    engine.destroy();
    Platform.shutdown();
```

Try this. It will work hopefully!!